# How to calculate Framebuffer pitch?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, opengl-es

I got a UI application which render output to an off-screen framebuffer in 16, 24 or 32 bpp respectively.

I need to calculate pitch, my understanding is pitch is number of bytes in one scanline, is it equal to screenx*bitsperpixel? Though apparently it does not produce correct result.

Can we have a formula (generic) to calculate pitch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/HowVideoCardsWork/):

> Buffers in video ram generally have a stride (also called pitch) associated with them. The stride is the width of the buffer in byte
>
> For example, if you have a 1024x768 pixel buffer at 16 bits/pixel (2 bytes/pixel), your stride would be:
>
> 1024 pixels * 2 bytes/pixel = 2048 bytes

So the generic way to calculate it is: buffer_width * bytes_per_pixel

However it is important to note that for tile renderers the frame buffer is not linear in memory and for that i think that the pitch is the width of a tile (i can't find sources to confirm this).

Comment: Thanks Raxvan, for reply, i was browsing the net and came across this formula to calculate pitch(sorry dont have link right now)...((( Framebuffer.Width * 32 ) + 31 ) & ~31 ) >> 3, this look like for 32bpp, what if i got 16bpp? Will it work if i just replace 32 with 16, any idea>

Comment: @Saqlain i think that formula calculates the width in bytes with padding, and it's hard to find a definitive good answer for your problem