# C++ writing to Framebuffer, wrong screensize

Tags: c++, linux

i try to write to the Linux framebuffer with c++, my problem is, that my program cant write to the whole screen, because the screensize i get is wrong. Although this code worked on an older VM, but i lost it.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
    fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
    size_t screensize = 0;
    long int location = 0;

    /* Open the file for reading and writing */
    int fbfd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
    if(fbfd == -1) {
        perror("Error: cannot open framebuffer device");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("The framebuffer device was opened successfully.\n");
    /* Get fixed screen information */
    if(ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading fixed information");
        exit(2);
    }

    /* Get variable screen information */
    if(ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading variable information");
        exit(3);
    }

    /* Figure out the size of the screen in bytes */
    screensize = vinfo.xres * vinfo.yres * vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8;
    printf("Screen size is %ld\n", screensize);
    printf("Vinfo.bpp = %d\n", vinfo.bits_per_pixel);

    /* Map the device to memory */
    auto fbp = static_cast<unsigned char*>(
        mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, 0));
    if(fbp == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Error: failed to map framebuffer device to memory");
        exit(4);
    }
    printf("The framebuffer device was mapped to memory successfully.\n");

    unsigned x = 0;
    unsigned y = 0; /* Where we are going to put the pixel */

    /* Figure out where in memory to put the pixel */
    location = (x + vinfo.xoffset) * (vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8) +
               (y + vinfo.yoffset) * finfo.line_length;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < vinfo.yres; i++) {
        for(uint32_t count = 1; count < vinfo.xres; count++) {
            fbp[location++] = 255; /* Some blue */
            fbp[location++] = 0;   /* A little green */
            fbp[location++] = 0;   /* A lot of red */
            fbp[location++] = 0;   /* No transparency */
        }
    }

    munmap(fbp, screensize);
    close(fbfd);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried increasing the screensize by multiplying it by 2 and it wrote to the full screen, but then my coordinates are wrong.

Comment: You're assuming a 32-bit-per-pixel frame buffer. That might be wrong.

Comment: maybe stride issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541111/how-to-calculate-framebuffer-pitch/20541631

Comment: You are writing four bytes in the double loop, what happens if you have 24 bits per pixel, or even 16? Not everyone has 32 bpp framebuffers. The loop does not account for line_length being larger that xres, there may be a gap in memory after each line before the next line starts.